# Blender can see Secret Files

Tags: scripting, add-on

I started up Blender after a few months of inactivity and wanted to update my custom addons. These addons were three `.py` script files that I created and then added to Blender using `Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install`.

They used to live in `C:\Users\verc\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons`, but that folder no longer exists. However I am still able to use all three addons within Blender and can see them here:

[image: Blender add-on UI]

I then re-created all the folders in the addon path and placed these two files within it:

[image: Windows Explorer showing the addon path]

I then went to add these `.py` files to Blender using the `Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install` button, and I can see one of the the old scripts!

[image: Blender file dialog]

As a test, I chose the oldest one from the list, however it says this error at the bottom of the Blender window:

[image: Blender error when adding an add-on]

I'm now convinced my PC is haunted. As proof here are all the windows open at once:

[image: Blender magic]

I'm installing Blender 3.3 LTS now (I currently have Blender 2.83 LTS installed (both are installed via the Windows Store)) and hoping it fixes this strange issue.